# How to read FaultException detail in consuming application?

Tags: wcf, webmethod, asp.net-4.5

In my WCF WebMethod I have the following code that provides some parameter validation.  It works okay and throws the FaultException:

```
Public Function BeforeCall(operationName As String, inputs() As Object) As Object Implements IParameterInspector.BeforeCall
    Dim u As MyAppUser = CType(inputs(0), MyAppUser)
    If u.FirstName Is Nothing Then
        Throw New FaultException(Of String)("First Name is Nothing", "First name must be a string value, and not empty.")
    End If
    Return u
End Function
```

In the consuming application I then call the method in such a way as to trigger the error (to check it works).  I catch the error to provide feedback, like this:

```
Dim u As New ServiceReference1.MyAppUser
u.FirstName = Nothing
u.Surname = "SomeSurname"
Dim i As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client
Dim u2 As New ServiceReference1.MyAppUser
Try
    u2 = i.GetDataUsingDataContract(u)
Catch fe As FaultException
    Trace.Warn("FaultException Caught")
    Trace.Warn(fe.Message)
    Exit Sub
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
End Try
```

Within the trace output however, I only see this:

> **FaultException Caught**
>
> **First name must be a string value, and not empty.**

Can anyone enlighten me please as to how I can read the FaultException detail as well as the reason provided when the FaultException was thrown?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the exception detail you would create a custom [fault contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx), which is included in the details of the [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx). Additionally, you would include the [FaultReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultreason.aspx) when throwing an exception. See the following articles for more information.

- [Fault Handling in WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx)
- [WCF error handling and some best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx)
- [Exception Handling in WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115006/Exception-Handling-in-WCF)

Comment: Yes I thought that might be the case.  So, by default, the detail string is not passed onto the consuming application?  So I suppose that string is for internal logging or something?  Thanks.

Comment: The detail is not necessarily a string. You can have `FaultException(Of ComplexType)`